# Specifying the cell size for a rasters on import into ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, convert, import, resolution

I've created an artificial surface terrain using Adobe Photoshop (for testing algorithms), and I would like to import the tiff into ArcGIS with the cell size set to a desired scale. At the moment, it comes in at 0.013888889m x 0.013888889m, and I want it to be 10m x 10m.

In theory, you could use the Rescale (Data Management) tool, but that doesn't appear to work. :(

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Edit world file, it will be 10/0.014 times larger in each direction

Comment: How did you georeference the tif? Are you adding it to an empty map document?

Answer (score 1):

Your cell size looks extremely small. Are you sure it's in a projected coordinate system? If it isn't, your cell size is not represented in meters. Check the coordinate system (right-mouse button on the layer -> properties -> source) to make sure. If it isn't in a cartesian system you can use the Reproject tool to transform your raster into a projected coordinate system to see what the output raster size is in meters. when it is in a projected coordinate system, You can use the Resample tool to specify an output cell size if the raster is not 10m resolution.